# Unable to get Postgresql LIMIT to work with UPDATE and subquery

Tags: postgresql

Why does the following query return more than `limit` records? There are about 272 records that exist but when a limit less than that is provided it always updates and returns all 272 records.

```
UPDATE thing 
SET status = 'status_2' 
WHERE thing.thing_id in (
  SELECT thing.thing_id 
  FROM thing 
  WHERE thing.status = ('status_1') AND 
  thing.c_id = ('c_id___1') AND 
  thing.name LIKE ('protocol://some/url/location/%')
  ORDER BY thing.status_1_date LIMIT (150) FOR UPDATE
) AND 
thing.c_id = ('c_id___1') AND 
thing.name LIKE ('protocol://some/url/location/%') 
RETURNING *
```

The same result is observed with alternative attempt:

```
UPDATE thing 
SET status = 'status_2' 
FROM (
  SELECT thing.thing_id 
  FROM thing 
  WHERE thing.status = ('status_1') AND 
  thing.c_id = ('c_id___1') AND 
  thing.name LIKE ('protocol://some/url/location/%')
  ORDER BY thing.status_1_date LIMIT (150) FOR UPDATE
) AS temp 
WHERE thing.thing_id = temp.thing_id AND 
thing.c_id = ('c_id___1') AND 
thing.name LIKE ('protocol://some/url/location/%') 
RETURNING *
```

Overview of problem: I need to select at most limit thing_ids and update all records containing this subset of thing_ids. For this set of records I am testing with there are no duplicate thing_ids but for others there could be.

Update: To demonstrate there are no duplicates I ran the following query:

````
SELECT COUNT(thing.thing_id)
FROM thing
WHERE thing.c_id = ('c_id___1') AND 
thing.name LIKE ('protocol://some/url/location/%'))
GROUP BY thing.thing_id```
````

With the results returning 272.

Update: I was able to derive a working solution but I'm going to leave the question open as I would like to understand what is wrong with the previous two implementations.

New Implementation:

```
UPDATE thing 
SET status = 'status_2' 
WHERE thing.thing_id in (
  SELECT a.thing_id 
  FROM thing a INNER 
  JOIN thing b on b.thing_id = a.thing_id 
  WHERE a.status = ('status_1') AND a.c_id = ('c_id___1') AND a.name LIKE ('protocol://some/url/location/%') 
  ORDER BY a.status_1_date, a.name LIMIT (150) FOR UPDATE
) RETURNING *
```

Update:
It turns out the join queyr isn't exactly what I need either. It will only update LIMIT rows if the number of unique thing.thing_ids is equal to the number of rows. If there are duplicate thing_ids it will exclude thing_ids so that the number of rows updates is less than limit.

This is the query plan for the join version of the query:
QUERY PLAN

```
Update on thing  (cost=31977.16..47319.15 rows=1 width=764)
"  ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=31977.16..47319.15 rows=1 width=764)"
"        Hash Cond: ((thing.thing_id)::text = (""ANY_subquery"".thing_id)::text)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on thing  (cost=0.00..14776.23 rows=215523 width=190)"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=31977.15..31977.15 rows=1 width=92)"
"              ->  Subquery Scan on ""ANY_subquery""  (cost=31977.13..31977.15 rows=1 width=92)"
"                    ->  Limit  (cost=31977.13..31977.14 rows=1 width=134)"
"                          ->  LockRows  (cost=31977.13..31977.14 rows=1 width=134)"
"                                ->  Sort  (cost=31977.13..31977.13 rows=1 width=134)"
"                                      Sort Key: a.status_1_date, a.name"
"                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=16392.67..31977.12 rows=1 width=134)"
"                                            Hash Cond: ((b.thing_id)::text = (a.thing_id)::text)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on thing b  (cost=0.00..14776.23 rows=215523 width=40)"
"                                            ->  Hash  (cost=16392.65..16392.65 rows=1 width=128)"
"                                                  ->  Seq Scan on thing a  (cost=0.00..16392.65 rows=1 width=128)"
"                                                        Filter: (((name)::text ~~ 'protocol://path/to/thing/%'::text) AND ((c_id)::text = 'c_id_1'::text) AND ((status)::text = 'status_2'::text))"
```

Query for table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS thing (
  name VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
  thing_id VARCHAR(255),
  c_id VARCHAR(255),
  status VARCHAR(255),
  etag VARCHAR(255),
  last_modified VARCHAR(255),
  size VARCHAR(255),
  status_1_date DATE
);
```

Query to insert sample data:

```
INSERT INTO thing (name,thing_id, c_id,status, etag, last_modified, size, status_1_date)
values 
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_1.file1', 'thing_1','c_id', 'status_1', 'etag', '1111', 200, '2023-09-29 09:00:01'),
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_1.file2', 'thing_1','c_id', 'status_1', 'etag', '1111', 200, '2023-09-29 09:00:02'),
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_2.file1', 'thing_2','c_id', 'status_1', 'etag', '1111', 200, '2023-09-29 09:00:03'),
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_2.file2', 'thing_2','c_id', 'status_1', 'etag', '1111', 200, '2023-09-29 09:00:04'),
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_2.file3', 'thing_2','c_id', 'status_1', 'etag', '1111', 200, '2023-09-29 09:00:05'),
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_3.file1', 'thing_3','c_id', 'status_1', 'etag', '1111', 200, '2023-09-29 09:00:06');
```

With LIMIT 2 the desired results to be returned would be as follows:
QUERY 1:

```
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_1.file1', 'thing_1','c_id', 'status_2', 'etag', '1111', 200, '2023-09-29 09:00:01'),
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_1.file2', 'thing_1','c_id', 'status_2', 'etag', '1111', 200, '2023-09-29 09:00:02'),
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_2.file1', 'thing_2','c_id', 'status_2', 'etag', '1111', 200, '2023-09-29 09:00:03'),
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_2.file2', 'thing_2','c_id', 'status_2', 'etag', '1111', 200, '2023-09-29 09:00:04'),
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_2.file3', 'thing_2','c_id', 'status_2', 'etag', '1111', 200, '2023-09-29 09:00:05'),
```

QUERY 2:

```
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_3.file1', 'thing_3','c_id', 'status_2', 'etag', '1111', 200, '2023-09-29 09:00:06')
```

Comment: 1) Are you sure `thing.thing_id` is unique? If there are duplicates, that could explain it. 2) Have you tried running the `select` subquery and verifying its results?

Comment: @Schwern I had considered that, it seems like there is something very obvious I am missing but I am sure there are no duplicates. It's like LIMIT is completely ignored even for the subquery. I'm not sure if it is the addition of the FOR UPDATE that breaks it.

Comment: @Schwern Okay, I just confirmed, removing the ```FOR UPDATE``` allows it to work. I think I need this though as there could be concurrent access to the same rows.

Comment: "*`FROM thing a INNER JOIN thing b on b.thing_id = a.thing_id`*" is weird and should not be necessary. Maybe it's the aliasing to `a` (instead of referring to `thing.…`) that has changed something?

Comment: Can you show us the query plans you get for these queries?

Comment: @Bergi Sure, I have updated the question. To your point, I suspect I am doing something round about and unnecessary because I am missing something.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data, expected results, and actual results? Maybe 10 rows and a limit of 5?

Comment: @Schwern I have updated the question with a query that represents the case I am trying to solve for. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: 1) `for update` should not be necessary within an update. I'm not sure why it would be causing problems. Can you show us the query plan without `for update`? 2) I agree with Bergi, the self-join seems odd. 3) Is `thing.thing_id` a primary key?

Comment: @CogitoErgoSum So `thing.thing_id` is not unique. That's likely to cause your problem. Lemme try some things. Could you supply a schema as well?

Comment: @CogitoErgoSum Your queries will never match your data. `protocol://some/url/location/%` vs `'protocol://full/path/to/thing/...`, and the c_id's don't match. It's important that we get a full, executable example.

Comment: Found [a thread about this behavior](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/15715-1eccf9c7dffc4093%40postgresql.org).

Comment: Working on getting a schema. I can't dump the schema of the database I am actually working in. The urls do match it is just a typo on my part.

Answer (score 3):

It's the `select for update` in a sub-query. [A thread on pgsql-bugs](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/16497.1553640836%40sss.pgh.pa.us) explains...

> The issue here is that the sub-SELECT is, in principle, executed afresh
> for every row of the outer query, and you do not have a guarantee that
> each such execution returns the *same* single row.  Ordinary query
> execution would provide such a guarantee, but you're using FOR UPDATE
> on a table that's being modified concurrently (including by this query
> itself), and therefore the guarantee disappears.
>
> You might think that since the sub-SELECT is uncorrelated with the outer
> query, there's no need to execute it more than once ... but that's an
> optimization, not part of the guaranteed semantics.  Without seeing an
> EXPLAIN for this query on your system, we can't know whether it's being
> done like that (though the fact that you're complaining suggests that
> it isn't).

And we can see from the `explain` that the subquery is inside a nested loop.

```
QUERY PLAN
Update on thing  (cost=16.14..31.42 rows=1 width=94)
  ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=16.14..31.42 rows=1 width=94)
        Join Filter: (thing.thing_id = "ANY_subquery".thing_id)
        ->  Seq Scan on thing  (cost=0.00..15.25 rows=1 width=38)
              Filter: ((name ~~ 'protocol://full/path/to/thing/%'::text) AND (c_id = 'c_id'::text))
        ->  Subquery Scan on "ANY_subquery"  (cost=16.14..16.16 rows=1 width=88)
              ->  Limit  (cost=16.14..16.15 rows=1 width=46)
                    ->  LockRows  (cost=16.14..16.15 rows=1 width=46)
                          ->  Sort  (cost=16.14..16.14 rows=1 width=46)
                                Sort Key: thing_1.status_1_date
                                ->  Seq Scan on thing thing_1  (cost=0.00..16.12 rows=1 width=46)
                                      Filter: ((name ~~ 'protocol://full/path/to/thing/%'::text) AND (status = 'status_1'::text) AND (c_id = 'c_id'::text))
```

[later in the thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/17074.1553696061%40sss.pgh.pa.us) there is a more detailed explanation.

> The seqscan+sort is going to find and return all the rows that meet
> that "filter" condition *as of the start of the query*.  The LockRows
> node is going to take the first of those and lock it, which will include
> finding and locking any newer version of the row that exists due to a
> concurrent update.  If there is a newer version, it then rechecks whether
> that version still satisfies the filter condition (via some magic we
> needn't get into here).  If so, it returns the row to the LIMIT node,
> which returns it up and then declares it's done, so we have found and
> locked exactly one row.  However, if that first row has been updated
> to a state that *doesn't* satisfy the filter condition, the LockRows
> node will advance to the next row of the seqscan+sort output, and lock
> and retest that one.  This repeats till it finds a row that does still
> satisfy the filter condition post-locking.
>
> So it's fairly easy to see how concurrent updates could cause this
> query to lock N rows, for some N larger than one.  But by itself
> this isn't a very satisfactory explanation for the query locking
> *all* the rows as you state happened.  All of them would've had
> to be concurrently updated to states that no longer satisfy the
> filter condition, and that seems pretty unlikely to happen as a
> consequence of a few other transactions individually doing the same
> type of query.

Their suggestion is to instead replace it with a CTE. That's generally good advice to use a CTE rather than a sub-query FROM, even if because it's just easier to read.

---

Note, your query will be faster and simpler if `thing` is given a primary key. Then you can identify individual rows and there's no need to repeat the where clause.

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/vaMGGDbx).

```
with these_things as (
  SELECT thing.id 
  FROM thing 
  WHERE thing.status = ('status_1') AND 
  thing.c_id = ('c_id') AND 
  thing.name LIKE ('protocol://full/path/to/thing/%')
  ORDER BY thing.status_1_date LIMIT (2)
)
UPDATE thing 
SET status = 'status_2'
from these_things
where thing.id = these_things.id
RETURNING *
```

Comment: Perhaps there is something I don't understand but if I use ```LIMIT 3``` it updates all of the rows for `thing_1` and `thing_2`. So 5 rows are updates for two thing_ids. The ultimate goal would be to update as many rows as necessary to update `LIMIT` unique `thing_id`s.

Comment: @CogitoErgoSum If you use `limit 3` on which query? `limit 3` works fine on the CTE because it is passing primary keys referring to specific rows between the select and update. The core problem is `things` lacks a way to refer to specific rows: a primary key. You want to select a set of rows, and then update only those specific rows. You're using `thing_id` to pass between the select and update, but `thing_id` is not unique to any row, so you risk updating other rows with the same `thing_id`. Instead, add a primary key to `things`, as I did, and update using the primary key.

Comment: @CogitoErgoSum Even if you repeat the whole `where` clause in both the select and update, there's no guarantee they will match the same rows; there's no `order by` in an update. Use a primary key.

Comment: I copied your query and ran it getting the results. `LIMIT 3` updates 5 rows that share 2 `thing_id`s. I don't understand what exactly is being limited. From the perspective of postgresql what is it limiting to 3?
I altered your query by `SELECT DISTINCT thing.thing_id, thing.status_1_date` and `ORDER BY thing.status_1_date, thing.thing_id LIMIT (2)` and this seems to produce the results I'm after though.

Comment: @CogitoErgoSum 1) [Works for me™](https://dbfiddle.uk/fOOSQDbm). Can you provide a demonstration in DBFiddle? 2) Without a limit, `select` would return all rows matching your query. With `limit 3` it only returns the first 3 matching rows. 3) I cannot stress enough that if you want to refer to specific rows, `things` needs a primary key. `select distinct thing_id, status_1_date` is only giving you the illusion of uniqueness. Consider if you have two rows with the same thing_id and same status_1_date, your work around will fail.

Comment: As far as the primary key, I am not in a situation where I can change that at the moment but I created an example to highlight my confusion: https://dbfiddle.uk/8SwxC-iU.  With `LIMIT 3` what has been limited to 3? The update counts are 5 rows with 2 thing_ids, 3 rows with 2 thing_ids, 3 rows 1 thing_id, and 1 row with 1 thing_id.

Comment: The goal of the query is to update as many rows as necessary to update the rows of up to `LIMIT` unique thing_ids.

Comment: @CogitoErgoSum `limit 3` restricts how many rows the select will return. That's it. If it would return (1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) then `limit 3` will limit the results to (1, 1, 2). I've [annotated your demo so you can see the result of the subquery at each step](https://dbfiddle.uk/7SzymfED).  I also fixed `status_1_date` to be a timestamp, otherwise you're just storing `2023-09-29` over and over again. From the demo we can see because the sub-query can return duplicates, you might update less than 3 thing_ids.

Comment: @CogitoErgoSum Your goal is still unclear. Look at [this data](https://dbfiddle.uk/E_lwjKwD), please. Which rows do you want to update?

Comment: @CogitoErgoSum Is `name` really the primary key?

Comment: Your example is part of the goal, due to the batching requirements I have to meet for where the query data goes to it isn’t completely resolved. I need to limit the data returned but ensure I get a complete set of data for the entities I am querying for. The thing_id is not the primary key in our database however the thing_id represents an entity that could be composed of data from N rows as indicated by a shared thing_id. I need to make sure I get a complete set of rows for all thing entities where LIMIT represents the total number of thing entities I am fetching data for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255502/discussion-between-schwern-and-cogito-ergo-sum).

Comment: The query in your answer fetches “some amount” of rows that is less than or equal to LIMIT observed in the example I made: https://dbfiddle.uk/8SwxC-iU. The first update only updates the rows for two thing entities as denoted by thing_1 and thing_2 but the number of rows that gets updates is 12. The desired behavior would be that each update will update all of the rows for 3 unique thing_ids with LIMIT 3.