# SQL Query Help in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

**Overview**
I am trying to develop a query that selects as many rows as necessary so that I update up to `LIMIT` unique `thing.thing_id`s and is ordered by the `status_1_date` column (meaning older things should be updated first). `thing_id` is NOT the primary key.

**Example Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS thing (
  name VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
  thing_id VARCHAR(255),
  c_id VARCHAR(255),
  status VARCHAR(255),
  etag VARCHAR(255),
  last_modified VARCHAR(255),
  size VARCHAR(255),
  status_1_date DATE
);
```

**Sample Data**

```
INSERT INTO thing (name,thing_id, c_id,status, status_1_date)
values 
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_1.file1', 'thing_1','c_id', 'status_1', '2023-09-29 09:00:01'),
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_1.file2', 'thing_1','c_id', 'status_1', '2023-09-29 09:00:02'),
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_2.file5', 'thing_2','c_id', 'status_1', '2023-09-29 09:00:02.5'),
  ('protocol://something else', 'thing_1','c_id', 'status_1', '2023-09-29 09:00:02.8'),
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_2.file1', 'thing_2','c_id', 'status_1', '2023-09-29 09:00:03'),
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_2.file2', 'thing_2','c_id', 'status_1', '2023-09-29 09:00:04'),
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_2.file3', 'thing_2','c_id', 'status_1', '2023-09-29 09:00:05'),
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_2.file4', 'thing_2','different', 'status_1', '2023-09-29 09:00:05'),
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_3.file1', 'thing_3','c_id', 'status_1', '2023-09-29 09:00:06'),
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_3.file2', 'thing_3','c_id', 'status_1', '2023-09-29 09:00:06.2'),
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_4.file1', 'thing_4','c_id', 'status_1', '2023-09-29 09:00:06.1'),
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_4.file2', 'thing_4','c_id', 'status_1', '2023-09-29 09:00:06.3'),
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_5.file1', 'thing_5','c_id', 'status_1', '2023-09-29 09:00:06.4'),
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_5.file2', 'thing_5','c_id', 'status_1', '2023-09-29 09:00:06.5'),
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_5.file3', 'thing_5','c_id', 'status_1', '2023-09-29 09:00:06.6'),
('protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_6.file1', 'thing_6','c_id', 'status_1', '2023-09-29 09:00:06.7');
```

**Desired Results**
Using this data I am trying to get a query that updates rows 1-6 and 7-9 when `LIMIT 3` is used. The rows for `thing_id`s `thing_5`, `thing_6`, and `thing_1` that match there `WHERE` clause should be updated.

**Additional Details**
The issues I am trying to solve is I work with a large database and I need to limit the data returned from it but ensure I get a complete set of data for the entities I am querying for. The `thing.thing_id` is not the primary key in our database however the `thing_id` represents an entity that could be composed of data from N rows as indicated by a shared `thing_id`. I need to make sure I get a complete set of rows for all thing entities where `LIMIT` represents the total number of thing entities I am fetching data for.

This question spawned from a previous thread but no solution: [Unable to get Postgresql LIMIT to work with UPDATE and subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77203452/unable-to-get-postgresql-limit-to-work-with-update-and-subquery)

**Issues with [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77217819/14179793)**

- It does not get the `thing_id` with the oldest file: https://dbfiddle.uk/GStIbrYA
- If two queries targeting the same `thing.c_id` and `thing.name` prefix run at the same time a double update will happen. This update in the database I am working on could be working with 100,000s of rows at one time so this is not desirable.

**Alternative Attempt 1**
It looks like `FOR UPDATE` might be needed to prevent the double update from occurring but it cannot be used with the window function.

```
with ranked_matching_things as (
  select
    dense_rank() over (order by thing_id) as thing_rank,
    name
  from thing
  where c_id = 'c_id'
    and name like 'protocol://full/path/to/thing/%'
  order by status_1_date
  for update
)
update thing
set status = 'CHANGED'
from ranked_matching_things
where thing.name = ranked_matching_things.name
  and ranked_matching_things.thing_rank <= 3

ERROR:  FOR UPDATE is not allowed with window functions
```

**Alternative Attempt 2**

- It does not get the `thing_id` with the oldest file first: https://dbfiddle.uk/tMG-vvU4
- It seems redundant with the duplication of the where clause

```
UPDATE thing
SET status = 'CHANGED'
FROM (
    SELECT name 
    FROM thing
    WHERE thing.thing_id in (
        SELECT DISTINCT thing.thing_id
        FROM thing
        WHERE c_id = 'c_id' AND name like 'protocol://full/path/to/thing/%' AND status = 'status_1'
        ORDER BY thing.thing_id
        LIMIT (3)
    ) AND thing.c_id = 'c_id' AND thing.name like 'protocol://full/path/to/thing/%' AND thing.status = 'status_1'
    ORDER BY thing.status_1_date
    FOR UPDATE
) AS rows
WHERE thing.name = rows.name 
RETURNING *
```

**Test Setup**
The following link may be useful for testing: https://dbfiddle.uk/ZTcbkqsF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to derive the following, likely suboptimal, solution.

**Query to get a list of valid `thing_id`s with the oldest file associated:**

```
SELECT thing_id, MIN(status_1_date)
FROM thing
WHERE status = ('status_1') AND c_id = ('c_id') AND name LIKE ('protocol://full/path/to/thing/%')
GROUP BY thing_id
```

**Query to get `LIMIT` `thing_id`s getting the `thing_id`s with the oldest file first:**

```
SELECT thing_id
FROM (
    SELECT thing_id, MIN(status_1_date) AS oldest_file
    FROM thing
    GROUP BY thing_id
) as thing_ids
ORDER BY thing_ids.oldest_file
LIMIT 3
```

**Query to get the necessary rows `FOR UPDATE`:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM thing
WHERE thing.thing_id in (
    SELECT thing_id
        FROM (
            SELECT thing_id, MIN(status_1_date) AS oldest_file
            FROM thing
            GROUP BY thing_id
        ) as thing_ids
    ORDER BY thing_ids.oldest_file
)
FOR UPDATE
```

**Query to `UPDATE` valid rows:**

```
WITH rows AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM thing
    WHERE thing.thing_id in (
        SELECT thing_id
            FROM (
                SELECT thing_id, MIN(status_1_date) AS oldest_file
                FROM thing
                WHERE status = ('status_1') AND c_id = ('c_id') AND name LIKE ('protocol://full/path/to/thing/%')
                GROUP BY thing_id
            ) as thing_ids
        WHERE thing.status = ('status_1') AND thing.c_id = ('c_id') AND thing.name LIKE ('protocol://full/path/to/thing/%')
        ORDER BY thing_ids.oldest_file
        LIMIT 3
    )
    FOR UPDATE
)
UPDATE thing
SET status = 'CHANGED'
FROM rows
WHERE thing.name = rows.name
RETURNING *
```

**Solution:** https://dbfiddle.uk/Z7trYUKa

**Revision 1:**

```
WITH thing_ids as (
    SELECT thing_id, MIN(status_1_date) AS oldest
    FROM thing
    WHERE status = ('status_1') AND c_id = ('c_id') AND name LIKE ('protocol://full/path/to/thing/%')
    GROUP BY thing_id
    ORDER BY oldest
    LIMIT 3
),
names AS (
    SELECT name
    FROM thing
    WHERE thing.thing_id IN (SELECT thing_id FROM thing_ids) AND thing.status = ('status_1') AND thing.c_id = ('c_id') AND thing.name LIKE ('protocol://full/path/to/thing/%')
    FOR UPDATE
)
UPDATE thing
SET status = 'CHANGED'
FROM names
WHERE thing.name = names.name
RETURNING *
```

**Revision 1 Solution:** https://dbfiddle.uk/dg8poZaA

I'm sure there must be some way to prevent the redundant `WHERE` clause but I have been unable to accomplish this so far.

**Revision 2 with No Repeated `WHERE`:**
I was able to solve for the redundant `WHERE` clause by creating an `UNLOGGED` table.

Create the table of all potential rows that match the `WHERE` clause:

```
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE rows AS (
  SELECT name, thing_id, status_1_date
  FROM thing
  WHERE status = ('status_1') AND c_id = ('c_id') AND name LIKE ('protocol://full/path/to/thing/%')
)
```

Update query:

```
UPDATE thing
SET status = 'CHANGED'
WHERE name IN (
  SELECT name
  FROM thing 
  WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM rows) AND
  thing_id IN (
    SELECT thing_id
    FROM rows
    GROUP BY thing_id
    ORDER BY MIN(status_1_date)
    LIMIT 3
  )
  FOR UPDATE
)
RETURNING *
```

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done with a limit, because it's too... limited. Instead we can use a [window function](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/). Let's break it down...

First, we identify the matching rows and put them in order.

```
select
  *
from thing
where c_id = 'c_id'
  and name like 'protocol://full/path/to/thing/%'
order by status_1_date;
```

Simple enough.

From those results, we need to pick the first 3 distinct matching thing_ids. We can add a column to the result with [`dense_rank`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-dense_rank-function/).

```
select
  dense_rank() over (order by thing_id) as thing_rank,
  *
from thing
where c_id = 'c_id'
  and name like 'protocol://full/path/to/thing/%'
order by status_1_date;
```

```
thing_rank  name    thing_id    c_id    status  status_1_date
1   protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_1.file1     thing_1     c_id    status_1    2023-09-29 09:00:01
1   protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_1.file2     thing_1     c_id    status_1    2023-09-29 09:00:02
2   protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_2.file5     thing_2     c_id    status_1    2023-09-29 09:00:02.5
2   protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_2.file1     thing_2     c_id    status_1    2023-09-29 09:00:03
2   protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_2.file2     thing_2     c_id    status_1    2023-09-29 09:00:04
2   protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_2.file3     thing_2     c_id    status_1    2023-09-29 09:00:05
3   protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_3.file1     thing_3     c_id    status_1    2023-09-29 09:00:06
4   protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_4.file1     thing_4     c_id    status_1    2023-09-29 09:00:06.1
3   protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_3.file2     thing_3     c_id    status_1    2023-09-29 09:00:06.2
4   protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_4.file2     thing_4     c_id    status_1    2023-09-29 09:00:06.3
5   protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_5.file1     thing_5     c_id    status_1    2023-09-29 09:00:06.4
5   protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_5.file2     thing_5     c_id    status_1    2023-09-29 09:00:06.5
5   protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_5.file3     thing_5     c_id    status_1    2023-09-29 09:00:06.6
6   protocol://full/path/to/thing/thing_6.file1     thing_6     c_id    status_1    2023-09-29 09:00:06.7
```

Now we have a way to identify the rows which correspond to the first three thing_ids: thing_1 has a rank of 1, thing_2 has a rank of 2, and thing_3 has a rank of 3.

We use `dense_rank`, not `rank`, to ensure the ranks are 1, 2, 3... Otherwise we'd have gaps.

Join with that sub-query on the primary key, and only update those with a rank <= 3.

```
with ranked_matching_things as (
  select
    dense_rank() over (order by thing_id) as thing_rank,
    name
  from thing
  where c_id = 'c_id'
    and name like 'protocol://full/path/to/thing/%'
  order by status_1_date
)
update thing
set status = 'CHANGED'
from ranked_matching_things
where thing.name = ranked_matching_things.name
  and ranked_matching_things.thing_rank <= 3
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/smMiR05y)

Comment: I have updated the question with some observations about the query in your answer if you would like to take a look.

Comment: @CogitoErgoSum I'm sorry, the question has changed too many times. When you ask a question, be sure you provide all the information, including sample data and expected results and any extra circumstances. You should ask a new question.